# Flask render_template working only with index.html

Tags: python, flask, flask-sqlalchemy

```
from flask import Flask, render_template, request, redirect, url_for, abort
import xlsxwriter
import testexecute
import json
import datetime
from requests.models import Response
#from flask_bcrypt import Bcrypt
from flask_sqlalchemy import SQLAlchemy
from config import BaseConfig

app = Flask(__name__)
app.config.from_object(BaseConfig)
#bcryptt = Bcrypt(app)
db = SQLAlchemy(app)
import constants

@app.route('/')
def index():
    return render_template('Index.html')

@app.route('/error')
def error():
    print("error")
    return render_template('errorPage.html')

@app.errorhandler(500)
def internal_server_error(e):
    print("internal_server_error")
    return render_template('500.html')

@app.errorhandler(400)
def page_not_found(e):
    print("page_not_found")
    return render_template('400.html'), 400

@app.route('/testExecution', methods=['POST'])
def invoke_testExecution():
    try:
        testexecute.execute(request)
        return "Test Started"
    except:
        print("Jenkins Exception")
        return "Test Aborted"
        #return redirect(url_for('error'))


if __name__ == '__main__':
    app.run(debug=False, host='0.0.0.0')
```

I have Index.html, errorPage.html, 500.html files under the templates directory. 'Index.html' is rendered fine. Messages "error" and "internal_server_error" are getting printed when I am routing to those but the templates "500.html" and "errorPage.html" are not rendered. In case of status 500, the content of 500.html is printed on the browser console but redirection doesn't take place! Please help!

`500.html`:

```
<html>
<h2>Server error</h2>
</html>
```

`errorPage.html`:

```
<!doctype html>
<html ng-app="horizonApp">
We are sorry to inform you that some error occured!!
Please <a href="#!/login" class="btn btn-link">Login</a> again!!

</html>
```

Comment: Could you share snippets the code in each `html` file? Everything looks OK from your Flask perspective... I'm wondering if something is amiss with your templates in `errorPage.html` or `500.html`?

Comment: Added! Please check.

Comment: OK I've re-created your project on my local machine and I can get all pages to render without any problems. Could you include all the code for your flask file (you only have the `app.route` section shown at present)?

Comment: I've added all the code. I am using angularjs as the front end, and doing http request from controller to app.py through a route and trying to display an error page if any exception occurs in python(flask).

Comment: You may not need to add all the code. And I don't see any code issue in your code. Could you let us know whats the error you are getting? status 404 or status 500 or something?

Comment: No. No error is coming. It's just not redirecting to that page.

Comment: I just noticed...in case of status 500 it's just printing the 500.html content on the browser console...but not redirecting to it..

Comment: render_template does not redirect you anywhere, by design. If you want to redirect elsewhere, use `redirect(url) `